# Using Python/Pandas to loop over several csv files in a folder and make changes to each csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I currently have several csv files in a folder.  I am wanting to use Python to loop over the files in the folder and make small changes to each csv file.  Please see my code below which is not currently working:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_to_view = "C:/path"

for file in os.listdir(folder_to_view):

    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    df.columns = ['Location','Subscriber','Speed','IP','Start','End','Bytes','Test Status','Comment']

    df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: What change are you wanting to make? Change the column names?

Comment: Yes, I'm just wanting to change the names of the columns

Comment: It might help if you indented the rest of your code to be inside your for loop

Comment: Thank you, looked like I had some formatting issues.  It should be fixed now.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that the issue is not forming the path correctly as the renaming of columns should be fine. `os.listdir()` returns a list of the files within that directory without the directory name prepended, so try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_to_view = "C:/path"

for file in os.listdir(folder_to_view):
    full_path = f'{folder_to_view}/{file}'
    df = pd.read_csv(full_path)
    df.columns = ['Location','Subscriber','Speed','IP','Start','End','Bytes','Test Status','Comment']
    df.to_csv(full_path, index=False)
```

Comment: This solution compiles and makes sense, however, no changes to the files are taking place.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  By changing "file" in the last line of the script to "full_path" the changes were saved.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ah yes sorry I missed changing the file in the saving part!